# Detect SSL protocol in C

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, tcp

I'm writing a server which is accepting incoming TCP connections and I would like to implement a simple way in C to detect if connection is SSL just inspecting few received bytes. Any help?

Comment: Assign a specific port? There is an initial negotiation phase, the first part of which is the ClientHello message; http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34780/checking-client-hello-for-https-classification

Comment: SSL as opposed to what? It matters what other protocols you have to detect. For example, if you have to detect whether it's SSL or HTTP, that's very easy -- the first character sent for HTTP is always an upper-case letter while for SSL, it never is.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible since the first message after the connection is established should be a "hello" message from the client. The first field in the message is the SSL/TLS version, then a timestamp follows - depending on the application layer protocol a plain client uses, this may be enough to figure out if the client connecting uses SSL/TLS or not.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4 for more details on the message structure.

Edit: here's a very similar question with an excellent answer: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34780/checking-client-hello-for-https-classification